# I could not able to find the related asp page for few data

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to find how the data are get populated or the sql query which is used to display the data in web page.

For Example i can able to get the asp page for the below data from href

```
                <td  align=left >1234</td><td  align=left >USD</td>
                <td  align=left ><a href="XXX.asp?s=det&x=33&xCase=XXXX&sKey=1234" target="_self">12-0336</a></td><td  align=right >123.00</td>
                <td  align=right >2.5</td>

                <td  align=right ></td>
            </tr>

           <tr >
```

but i could not able find the asp page or query for the below data.

```
                <td  align=left >123456</td><td  align=left >USD</td><td  align=left >12-3456</td><td  align=right >($XX.00)</td><td  align=left >Adjustment</td>


            </tr>
```

Kindly advise

Comment: and how we can if you not that you have the full source code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found it that asp page.